Proving there exist $g,h$ where $g = \Theta(h)$ and $f(x) = g(x) - h(x)$ for a function $f$
I am trying to prove that for any function $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, there exist $2$ functions $g : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $h : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $f(x) = g(x) - h(x)$ and $g = \Theta (h)$. I am unsure of my proof as the claim that functions can be the same theta classes no matter how much their difference grows seems very counter-intuitive to me. Here is my proof:
Let $c$ be any real number greater than or equal to $1$. Define $h(x) = \frac {f(x)} c$ and $g(x) = f(x) + \frac {f(x)} c$. Let $k=2c$. The inequality $h(x) \le g(x) $ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, as $f(x)$ is a positive number for all $x$; therefore $g = \Omega(h)$. The inequality $g(x) \le k \cdot h(x)$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ , as $\frac {f(x)} c < f(x) $ for all $x$; therefore $g = O (h)$. Therefore $g = \Theta(h)$ and $f(x) = g(x) - h(x)$.
Is my proof correct? Even if it is, are there any easier ways to show the claim?

The way you've done it, you have $g-h=-f$, no?

@GerryMyerson thanks I believe I fixed that error. Is my proof correct now?

Looks OK to me.

A simpler proof is: $g:=2f$ and $h:=f$ do the job.
